# How to stop Word 2003 creating shadow icons on my Windows 10 Pro desktop?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word-2003

Word 2003 creates shadow "temporary" icons on my Win10Pro desktop. They disappear as soon as I press the F5 key, but for as long I don't press it they build up and sometimes there are tens of them.

How can I stop Word 2003 creating them in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I've found the answer to my own question, a few minutes after posting it. The solution is to **set the Desktop directory not to show hidden files and directories**. This works. Of course the temporary files will still be there in some sense; it's just that now the desktop won't contain icons for them. I'm not sure what happens to them at power down. If they get ~F5ed at that point, then all is well and good. If not, then I guess eventually they might clog something up, in which case I remain in need of a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

When Word works on a document, it creates a temporary file. It’s that temporary file that Word makes all of its changes in; saves things to disc on and so forth, so that it doesn’t modify the original file until you’re actually done and actually say "Save".

To avoid confusion, Word mangles a bit the name of this temporary file to be
a little different than the edited file name and also makes it hidden,
so you are not supposed to ever see it.
Unless, that is, that hidden files are set to be shown.

The hidden file is closed whenever Word closes correctly the document.
If a crash happens, the contents of the hidden file will be used to recover
your lost work.

This is what’s happening here.

For this to happen, you have to actually have the document on your desktop.
It is really a *bad idea* to clutter the desktop with items that are not icons,
especially as sometimes Windows takes some liberties with the desktop.

You can avoid this problem by just editing your files inside some folder that
you could dedicate to your documents.
There would not then be any "ghost" icons that you are not supposed to
click by mistake, as this could cause a problem with the main file being edited.